# Миграция в Laravel. Как сделать столбец внешним ключом на разные таблицы в зависимости от другого столбца?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, миграция

Имеется таблица

```php
$table->bigIncrements('id');
$table->integer('type');
$table->foreignId('model_id')->constrained(??);
```

Хочется, что бы в зависимости от значения поля type была связь с разными таблицами. Например, если type = 1, то ->constrained(Table1). Если type = 2, то ->constrained(Table2).
Возможно ли провернуть такой трюк?

Логика подсказывает, что можно создать просто

```php
$table->integer('model_id')
```

И устанавливать связь уже через отношения, правда не совсем очевидно как это реализовать отношение одно, а таблицы разные

```php
class Table_full extends Model
{
    function table1()
    {    
         $this->hasMany(?)->where('Table_full.type', ?);
    }
}

class Table1 extends Eloquent
{
    function TableFull()
    {    
         $this->belongsTo('Table_full')->where('Table_full.type', 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: *Возможно ли провернуть такой трюк?* Такой "трюк" невозможен даже на уровне SQL, и тем более невозможен на уровне фреймворка. Обходитесь программным связыванием в момент запрашивания данных.

Comment: Это архитектурная ошибка, не стоит так делать... Нужны разные связи - добавьте второе поле

Comment: @InDevX, связь нужна одна, но на разные модели. Ну или как-то так)

Comment: @KordDEM когда 2 разных таблицы это 2 связи, через отношения сделать вариант плохой, если вы для человека код пишите, если для интерпретатора то разницы вообще никакой и тупить что угодно можно

Comment: @InDevX, я в качестве тренировки на кошках)